# Custom GridView delete button

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, gridview

How can I customize automatically generated command button, e.g. `Delete`?

I want to add a client confirmation on deleting and in the same moment I want this button would be generated on setting `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"`. Is it possible??

I can add a custom button this way:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete?')">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

but it will be not automatically localized and will be not generated on setting `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"`!

Answer (score 2):

I would rather recommend using the RowDataBound-event instead of the PreRender-event.

There you can easily have access to your Elements in the specific row.
(I think the solution Kelsey posted might have problems with paging (maybe just combined with ajax))

Give the Linkbutton an ID and subsribe to the RowDataBound-event.

```
  void gv_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      LinkButton _foo = e.Row.FindControl("LINKBUTTONID") as LinkButton;
      if(_foo != null)
      {
       _foo.OnClientClick = "insert localized text here";
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by implementing the `PreRender` event for the grid.

Here is some basic psuedo code:

```
protected void yourGrid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grd = (GridView)(sender);

    // iterate through all your rows and look for the button
    // make sure to add code to verify your rows, columns, and control bounds are valid
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < grd.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        LinkButton btn = grd.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[deleteButtonColumnIndex].Controls[0] as LinkButton;

        // Here you have access to the button so change it to do what you need.
        btn.OnClientClick = string.Format("return confirm('{0}?')", btn.Text);
    }
}
```

Also if you want it baked in you will probably need to extend the GridView and implement your own code.  See the following thread:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1396268/3011988.aspx#3011988

Comment: @abatishchev just following up, did you ever get this worked out?

Comment: No, I gave it up and my custom delete button has always the same, hard-coded, english label

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a .vb file/class by rightclicking on your root file in the Solutions Explorer tab (I use VWD). Select Add New and choose Class page. It will offer to create the App_Code folder which is where your shared classes will reside. Name the file/class as "DeleteButtonField.vb" and click OK.

It should then open a new .vb file called DeleteButtonField and you can copy and paste or enter the code below. (Note that you can use Intellisense to complete the really long bit of code that defines the Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCell(........).)

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Namespace myControls
Public Class DeleteButtonField
  Inherits ButtonField
  Private _confirmText As String = "Delete This Record?"
  Public Property ConfirmText() As String
     Get
        Return _confirmText
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As String)
        _confirmText = value
     End Set
  End Property
  Public Sub New()
     Me.CommandName = "Delete"
     Me.Text = "Delete"
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Sub InitializeCell(ByVal cell As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell, ByVal cellType As System.Web.UI.WebControl.DataControlCellType, ByVal rowState As System.Web.UI.WebControl.DataControlRowState, ByVal rowIndex As Integer)
     MyBase.InitializeCell(cell, cellType, rowState, rowIndex)
     If cellType = DataControlCellType.DataCell Then
        Dim button As WebControl = CType(cell.Controls(0), WebControl)
        button.Attributes("onclick") = String.Format("return confirm('{0}');", _confirmText)
     End If
 End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Save the .vb file. Then in your .aspx page, open up the page in source mode and find your GridView definition (i.e.   tags. You can choose where you want the Delete button to appear, either the first position, second or so on. Make sure that you choose a text position so that you don't change any of the  definitions, and add the following

```
<custom:DeleteButtonField ConfirmText="Are you sure that you want to delete this record?"></custom:DeleteButtonField>
```

You also need to add a line at the top of your page after the <%@ Page ...> as follows

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" Namespace="myControls" %>`
This also needs to be added on every page where you intend using the new Delete Button in a GridView. There may be a way to set this up as a default in web.config; I'm not there at this stage of my learning.

Save your .aspx page and test. You have now defined a common Sub (which defines a standard Delete button and its behaviour) that you can attach to any GridView in your application.