# how to display alert by using serverside code in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to execute following code on button click but the follwing code executes when I refresh the page as well. I don't want that behaviour. Please help me.

```
string str = "Are you sure, you want to Approve this Record?";
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Popup", "ConfirmApproval('" + str + "');", true);
```

Comment: Just to make sure. You want when you click a button to get a confirm message first. Is that right?

Comment: yes but i dont want when i refresh the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your question in quite unclear. I assumed you use ASP.NET C# , here is the way:

```
public static class ClientMessageBox
{

    public static void Show(string message, Control owner)
    {
        Page page = (owner as Page) ?? owner.Page;
        if (page == null) return;

        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(owner.GetType(),
            "ShowMessage", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>",
            message));

    }

}
```

then, in your page (remember to reference the class above):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientMessageBox.Show("Hello World", this);
}
```

See if it helps in your case.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at putting your alert in to the OnClientClick method of the button.

E.g. (add in your other required attributes and click handler)

```
<asp:Button ID="ApproveButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you certain you want to approve this record?');" />
```

If the user clicks OK your normal click code will run but if they cancel the function returns false so the click won't be processed.

Comment: it is working fine on button click but sorry i am  using gridveiw control. when i press delete event on gridview control then i want confirmation message is it possible

Comment: @user746909 Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458351/custom-gridview-delete-button/2458469#2458469. I think it solves the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Add `OnClientClick` to your button

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to Approve this Record?')" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **marto'ss** and **Chris W's** code. If you want a clean HTML Markup, use this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string script = "javascript:return confirm('Are you certain you want to approve this record?');";
        //id of your button
        button.Attributes.Add("onclick", script):
    }
}
```